# How to unit test generic service proxy from WCF service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, proxy

I'm looking to consume a vendor's SOAP API and expose it through our own unified WCF implementation. Since I don't have control over the source service interface, I'm forced into using a Service Reference and code gen client classes.

**An example of one of these client classes**

```
public partial class CompanyApiSoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Cwx.Repository.ConnectWise.CompanyService.CompanyApiSoap>, Cwx.Repository.ConnectWise.CompanyService.CompanyApiSoap
```

To handle calls to the different services generically, I went with the following generic proxy approach:

```
public class ServiceClientProxy<TChannel> : IServiceClientProxy<TChannel> where TChannel : ICommunicationObject
{
    private readonly TChannel _innerChannel;
    public ServiceClientProxy(TChannel innerChannel)
    {
        _innerChannel = innerChannel;
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<TChannel, TResult> operation)
    {
        var result = default(TResult);

        try
        {
            if (_innerChannel.State != CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                _innerChannel.Open();
            }
            result = operation(_innerChannel);
        }
        catch (CommunicationException)
        {
            _innerChannel.Abort();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            _innerChannel.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _innerChannel.Abort();
            throw;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _innerChannel.Close();
    }
}
```

Herein lies my problem. In order for my proxy generic to work, TChannel needs to implement ICommunicationObject. I don't get that implementation off of the CompanyApiSoap interface, but rather the concrete ClientBase generic implementation. Naturally, if I want to unit test usage of the service proxy generic via IoC container, I can't constrain the generic type to a concrete type.